# Филтрация данных БД

Tags: база-данных

Каким образом лучше фильтровать данные? В самом запросе к БД или выполнив запрос, отфильтровать полученные данные в программе. Есть ли разница? При одном способе хранения данных получается 13 полей в БД и становится возможным использования WHERE. При другом способе 2 поля и невозможно использовать оператор WHERE, нужно фильтровать в программе.

UPDATE#1 Забыл еще, БД локальна.

Comment: Я думаю, это зависит от колличества данных. До определенного колличества лучше фильтровать на клиенте (до 5000 клиенты хорошо справляются даже на js), а когда колличество такое что клиент не справляется - фильтровать where. А когда уже сервер не справится - тогда оптимизировать базу.

Comment: Вы можете пояснить: `При другом способе 2 поля и невозможно использовать оператор WHERE` - почему невозможно использовать оператор WHERE?

Comment: Если Вы выгрузите все данные клиенту, то сможете менять фильтры, не перезапрашивая данных. Но это ценой расхода памяти на клиенте и трафика - весь объём данных будет ползти дольше, чем фильтрованный.

Comment: @MaxU Потому что при другом способе 12 полей объединяются в одно, а мне нужно фильтровать по каждому из полю. Как это сделать c помощью SQL при таком случаи, незнаю.

Comment: @van9petryk, так может тогда стоит задать соответсвующий вопрос? ;-)

Comment: @MaxU я уверен что это будет геморой с костылями

Comment: @van9petryk, использование __локальной__ БД многое меняет - тут надо сравнивать что будет быстрее и эфективнее. А по поводу `12 полей объединяются в одно` - это "anti-pattern" в мире RDBMS систем,  я бы постарался избегать таких решений...

Comment: @MaxU  да там данные связанные между собой. Я бы даже сказал по другому, разбивать ли строку на 12 полей. Сама строка 12 символов. Нужно проверять каждый символ строки. Если не разбивать на 12 то нужно будет разбивать с помощью процедуры Substring с помощью SQL либо в программе

Answer (score 4):

Все зависит от того как Вы хотите распределить нагрузку. Если на sql - тогда лучше фильтровать с помощью запроса. Если на сервер - тогда с помощью программы. Из моего опыта, лучше всего написать хороший запрос с условиями, как правило, sql вернет запрос быстрее (особенно если это 500 000 строк) чем обрабатывать эти данные на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему второй вариант (фильтрация на клиенте) не имеет практически никаких преимуществ.

Дисковые операции - самые дорогие операции для БД. Соответственно для того чтобы фильтровать на клиенте (по отношению к серверу БД) сначала надо прочитать **все** записи в БД (если данные не закешированы, то это чтение с диска). Кроме того в БД можно создать необходимые индексы, соединять (join) данные из разных таблиц и т.д.

Есть случаи когда невозможно обработать данные на сервере БД (например машинное обучение) или когда надо выбрать подмножество (subset) данных и по-разному фильтровать его - тогда есть смысл сделать первичную фильтрацию на сервере БД, а дальше фильтровать (обрабатывать) небольшое подмножество уже на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Лучший подход отфильтровать все на уровне БД. Зная хорошо SQL можно получить практически любой требуемый набор данных. Есть смысл тянуть все в программу обработчик, если тебе нужен весь набор в клиенте и возможность фильтрации, тогда это всего лишь одно обращение к БД.